# Python Session cookies not persisting

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

I am trying to login to a webpage and then perform a subsequent GET request from the same domain which should use the cookie set from the initial POST.

The initial POST is performed successfully and the response is the expected page, however any subsequent GET requests shoot me back to the login page.

Code:

```
s = requests.Session()
url1 = 'https://www.sitename.com'
url2 = 'https://www.sitename.com/cookie_dependent_resource'
creds = {'un': 'username', 'pw': 'password'}
r1 = s.post(url, data=creds)
r2 = s.get(url2)
```

I am new to this but obviously doing something wrong. Help a newbie please! :-)

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: Can you confirm that `s.cookies` shows the expected cookies after the first `post` call?

Comment: Affirmative. I can iterate through s.cookies successfully after the initial POST.

Comment: Clarification: Both r1.cookies & r2.cookies appear identical when iterating through them.

Comment: You're using the session correctly, and I doubt a bug in `requests` is the issue. Are you sure there aren't any other (hidden) form fields that you'd need to submit? Possibly a CSRF token?

Comment: @LukasGraf - I am positive. One thing to add which is very bizarre: When I set r2 again (r2 = s.get(url2)) after waiting about 10-20 minutes it successfully grabs the page. If I attempt to pull that second URL before that 10-20 minute window it fails.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was with the server I was connecting to, not my code. I ended up attempting this same operation with a different server and it worked like a charm.

Thanks to everyone who tried to sanity check my work! It was much appreciated.